# Can Azure Storage be Changed from General Purpose to BlobStorage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a storage account that is general purpose but am only using it for blob storage. As utilization grows, my costs are going up and find that I'd prefer to have a BlobStorage account. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to switch the type. Is this possible to do? If so, how? If not, is there any easy way to copy the blobs to a new BlobStorage account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this [info about AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs#copy-blobs-between-storage-accounts). That's the tool that can help you to do the migration.

> You can use AzCopy to copy blobs to other storage accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#copying-data-into-a-storage-account), you need to migrate data to a new account:

> When you upgrade to a general-purpose v2 account from a general-purpose v1 or Blob storage account, your data is automatically migrated. Microsoft recommends this pathway for upgrading your account. **However, if you decide to move data from a general-purpose v1 account to a Blob storage account, then you'll need to migrate your data manually, using the tools and libraries described below.**

The original doc suggests 4 ways of migration: AzCopy, Data movement library, REST API or client library, and Azure Import/Export service, you can read it for details.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

https://medium.com/@asimnazir.uet/azure-storage-migration-from-gpv1-to-gpv2-2ad9584a8d98

Microsoft recommends using a general-purpose v2 storage account for most scenarios. It can easily be upgraded from a general-purpose v1 or Blob storage account to a general-purpose v2 account with no downtime and without the need to copy data.
General-purpose v2 storage accounts support the latest Azure Storage features and incorporate all of the functionality of general-purpose v1 and Blob storage accounts.
Pricing
General-purpose v2 accounts deliver the lowest per-gigabyte capacity prices for Azure Storage, as well as industry-competitive transaction prices.
NOTE: Write Operations in v1 are $0.0004 per 10,000 and this goes up to $0.05 in v2. A customer with $1 of blob write charges in v1 will have a bill of $125 in v2.